# Chrome Remote Desktop freezes when logging in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome, freeze, remote

I have an Ubuntu host and a Windows client from which I am trying to access the Ubuntu machine. I set up the connection and I can see the Ubuntu host. I can enter my pin and see the log in screen.

If I enter a wrong password everything works fine and it tells me that it's not correct.

However, the problem comes when I actually enter the correct password. If the password entered is correct, the screen freezes and I never actually see the desktop. The machine is not completely frozen as I can see my mouse moving and interact with the status bar, however, it never logs me in.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue?

Comment: Please clarify your release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu desktop and servers use a *yy.mm* format, however specialist snap based releases do use *yy* format (not multiple releases per year), but there is no Ubuntu 18; the closest by name is Ubuntu Core 18 (for IoT appliances, a snap based *yy* release).

Comment: did you find a fix / any updates?